# import libssh library in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio, libssh

I'm currently trying to include the *libssh* library on Visual Studio 2017.
I already downloaded [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/get-it/) but I don't know exactly what am I supposed to do with cmake. Where should I include files in Visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you downloaded is the source code of libssh. So before you can link it to any of your own projects, you need to build libssh first. This were `cmake` comes in. `CMake` is the build system used for libssh.

In the source tree, which you have downloaded, you will find a file named `INSTALL`. It contains descriptions about all the prerequisites and a how you can use `cmake` to build libssh yourself.

If you prefer it, you can alternatively download a prebuilt version of libssh from https://www.libssh.org/files/win32/0.5/. The downside is, this is a quite dated version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can use vcpkg to download C++ libraries like libshh through command prompt. In this way the required dll's will be automatically include in your project directory, once you include the related header file in your project and compile it. See https://www.libssh.org/get-it/.